# What exactly should a Symfony2 bundle contain?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I know a Symfony2 bundle should contain a common set of features. However, how granular do you define that set of features? For example, I have a ContentBundle which deals with creating and editing content. Then I have a TaxonomyBundle which handles tagging and categories etc. Finally I have a PollsBundle, which deals with polls.

The trouble I'm having is that the doctrine entities rely on entities in other bundles. For example I have an entity 'Type' in TaxonomyBundle, and a 'Poll' in PollBundle belongs to 'Type'. Finally 'Type' belongs to 'Content' in the ContentBundle.

Am I being *too* granular when trying to separate concerns? Should things like content and taxonomy be a part of the same bundle?

tl;dr how wide a scope, in terms of features should a Symfony2 bundle be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Symfony best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html#application-bundles) :

> But a bundle is meant to be something that can be reused as a
>   stand-alone piece of software. If UserBundle cannot be used "as is" in
>   other Symfony apps, then it shouldn't be its own bundle. Moreover
>   InvoiceBundle depends on ProductBundle, then there's no advantage to
>   having two separate bundles.

So it looks that in your case this rule applies:

> Best Practice
>
> Create only one bundle called AppBundle for your application logic

Comment: Ahaaa! Yes that makes more sense. I notice in the best practice guide, they mention 'blog bundle'. Well a blog bundle could contain content, taxonomy and polls... Thanks that's really helped :)